# How can I see how much the temperature has changed in x number of hours and then send an alert?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which shows me the current temperature with a phone sensor, but I want to see how much the temperature has changed in a hour and send a notification to the user.

For example if the current temperature is 30°C and in a hour temperature decreased by more than 5°C (24 or less °C), I want to send a notification to the user and tell them to be aware or something.

I already made the basic app to show me the temperature value whenever it's changing but I don't know what to do next.

**Later Edit*:**
This is my service class that I created and now I'm trying to understand the flow but it's pretty hard to me. How this will work? I mean how can I store in **onStartCommand** method a value of a temperature from **onSensorChanged** method once in an hour?

```
public class TemperatureService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor temperatureSensor;
    private boolean isTemperatureSensorPresent;
    private float lastKnownTemp;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) != null) {
            temperatureSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
            isTemperatureSensorPresent = true;
        } else{
            isTemperatureSensorPresent = false;
        }
        if(isTemperatureSensorPresent) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, temperatureSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        lastKnownTemp = sensorEvent.values[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to read the temperature on background to send the notification to the user.

Folowing the doc:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Create a class that extend from Service

```
public class TemperatureService extends Service {

}
```

And define it in the manifest like:

```
<application ... >
      <service android:name=".TemperatureService" />
      ...
  </application>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm struggling with how can I store the value of temperature once in an hour in my service. I edited my original post.